# Valgrind status says no memory leak possible but shows errors in Error Summary

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have been learning C++ and recently I have arrived on the topic of operator overloading. I overloaded various operators as a practice of creating the `Mystring` *(similar to std::string)* class. All of the operators worked well except for the `+=` operator. It works as expected and also there is no memory leak as per my **valgrind status** but in the Error Summary, it shows errors. I have written `Mystring` class for various operators but I am facing a problem only for the `+=` operator so I will be sharing code only related to this problem.

***declarations.hpp***

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cctype>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

class Mystring {
private:
    char *str;
public:
    Mystring();                                         //No-args constructor
    Mystring(const char *s);                            //Overloaded constructor
    Mystring(const Mystring &source);                   //Copy constructor(deep copy)
    Mystring(Mystring &&source);                        //Move constructor
    ~Mystring();                                        //Destructor
    Mystring &operator=(const Mystring &rhs);           //Copy assignment
    Mystring &operator=(Mystring &&rhs);                //Move assignment

    //Operators as member methods
    Mystring operator+=(const Mystring &rhs);           //Concatenates lhs += rhs

    //Displays the str
    void display() const;                               //Displays the object's string
```

**definitions.cpp**

```cpp
#include "declarations.hpp"

//No-args constructor
Mystring::Mystring()
    :str{nullptr} {
    str = new char[1];
    *str = '\0';
}

//Overloded constructor
Mystring::Mystring(const char *s)
    :str{nullptr} {
    if (s == nullptr) {
        str = new char[1];
        *str = '\0';
    } else {
        str = new char [std::strlen(s) + 1];
        std::strcpy(str,s);
    }
}

//Copy constructor(Deep copy)
Mystring::Mystring(const Mystring &source)
    :str{nullptr} {
    str = new char[std::strlen(source.str) + 1];
    std::strcpy(str, source.str);
}

//Move constructor
Mystring::Mystring(Mystring &&source) 
    :str{source.str} {
    source.str = nullptr;
}

//Destructor
Mystring::~Mystring() {
    delete [] str;
}

//Copy assignment
Mystring &Mystring::operator=(const Mystring &rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;
    
    delete [] str;
    str = new char [std::strlen(rhs.str) + 1];
    std::strcpy(str, rhs.str);
    return *this;
}

//Move assignment
Mystring &Mystring::operator=(Mystring &&rhs) {
    if (this == &rhs)
        return *this;

    str = rhs.str;
    rhs.str = nullptr;

    return *this;
}

//Displays the objects's string
void Mystring::display() const {
    cout << str << " : " << std::strlen(str) << endl;
}

//Concatenates lhs += rhs
Mystring Mystring::operator+=(const Mystring &rhs) {
    char *buff = new char[std::strlen(str) + std::strlen(rhs.str) + 1];
    std::strcpy(buff, str);
    std::strcat(buff, rhs.str);
    delete [] str;
    str = new char [std::strlen(buff)];
    std::strcpy(str,buff);
    delete [] buff;
    return *this;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "declarations.hpp"

int main() {
    // +=
    cout << "\n===========================" << endl;
    cout << "Overloaded (+=)" << endl;
    Mystring s1 = "abc";
    s1.display();                       //abc
    s1 += "ABC";
    s1.display();                       //abcAbc
    Mystring s2 = "xyz";
    s2.display();                       //xyz
    s2 += "XYZ";
    s2.display();                       //xyzXYZ
    s1 += s2;                           
    s1.display();                       //abcABCxyzXYZ
    cout << "===========================\n" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output(I am getting output as expected)**

```
===========================
Overloaded (+=)
abc : 3
abcABC : 6
xyz : 3
xyzXYZ : 6
abcABCxyzXYZ : 12
===========================
```

**But here comes the problem where valgrind shows no memory leak possible but also gives me 19 errors in the Error Summary**

```
==23343== 
==23343== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23343==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23343==   total heap usage: 15 allocs, 15 frees, 73,822 bytes allocated
==23343== 
==23343== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==23343== 
==23343== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==23343== ERROR SUMMARY: 19 errors from 19 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Please do let me know where and what is the mistake so that I can avoid it in the future.

Comment: I can tell you that your `Mystring::Mystring(const char *s)` constructor is not going to do what you think it should.  You initialize `str` with `nullptr` so you'll always enter `if (s == nullptr)` and not the `else` case.

Comment: Alternative tool address sanitizer reports buffer overflow: https://godbolt.org/z/G7hefq1Yd  You have forgotten that string in C needs terminating zeros!

Comment: Here after adding `+ 1` it works: https://godbolt.org/z/T68xdqxEo

Comment: It is nice you are using Valgrind to keep track of memory managment, but try address sanitizer. In most cases it is way better then Valgrind. It is compiler functionality so just add respective flag to your build process (in debug mode).